# In Snowflake, How to change the current ownership role of the table to new role where current role user are not exist/active

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to select the table(T1) which has different role as owner.
Then I have granted the access to DB or SCHEMA using ACCOUNTADMIN privilege still I am not able to access sample table(T1).
Then I thinking to connect any one of existing user to the role and get an access, unfortunately no user are active in that role.

Please share your suggestion/opinion for how to get an access or how to change the ownership of the table. Appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi can you please show the commands that you executed , did you try this GRANT ownership on table  table_name   TO ROLE new_role copy current grants;